# 5 divs replacing each other onclick

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a jquery animaton of divs that replace each others , it work good but when clicking on the black block( mydiv1) it doesnt return to its place why?

Check this link [jquery_animation_divs](http://sarafandnet.com/flash.html)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.nn').click(function(){
            var l = $(this).css('left');

            $(this).animate({
                left: '-=' + l
            }, 1500, "easeOutBounce", function(){
                // callBack
                $("#divmain").css("background-color", $(this).css("background-color"));
            });

            $('.ff').animate({
                left: '+=' + l
            }, 1500, "easeOutBounce", function () {
                // callBack
            });

            var ff = $('.ff');
            ff.removeClass('ff').addClass('nn');

            $(this).removeClass('nn').addClass('ff');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `.bind()` (via `.click()`) which only applies to elements that match your selector at the time you run the event binding code. You want to use `.delegate()` or `.live()` so that the black block will be included in the set of matched elements.

Here is a jsfiddle of your exact code with `.click(` replaced by `.live('click',` : http://jsfiddle.net/Uv2GE/

Comment: Although this solves the problem, this is not the right usage of `.live`. Live is used to bind events for elements not present in the DOM at time of the event declaration.

Comment: thanks a lot , i want also to prevent user from clicking on the boxes during animation? best regards

Answer (score 0):

When the document loads, the black square has class "ff", not "nn", so the `click` handler is never applied to it.

Replace

```
      $('.nn').click(function () {
```

with

```
      $('.nn').live("click",function () {
```

and it will work fine.

Comment: @KassemShehady You didn't say that in your original question. It's not really fair for you to withhold answers now based on that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are never added the click event to `myDiv1`. When you first load the page the function `$(document).ready(function ()` is setting all the `.nn` classes click functions but when you change `.ff` to `.nn` class it doesn't have a click function.